# NSDirectoryEnumerator And Subfolders

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsarray

I have an iPhone app that searches a folder, collates an an array of all the audio files, and lets them be played back. The problem is that if there is a subfolder within the folder I am searching, it will just skip over it/not go into its contents.

My code is as follows:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectory];

 NSString *pname;

 while (pname = [direnum nextObject])
{
      [musicArray addObject:[pname stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
}
```

What I want to do is continue to search its subfolders, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 13):

It does it automatically.  [From the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDirectoryEnumerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000307-506):

> An enumeration is recursive, including the files of all subdirectories, and crosses device boundaries. An enumeration does not resolve symbolic links, or attempt to traverse symbolic links that point to directories.